# VS2012 Web project runs in VS Dev Server, but not in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I have an MVC v3 project I've inherited. (I'm not that familiar with web stuff.) The project runs fine in Debug mode using the Visual Studio Development Server.

However, whenever I try to run it via IIS locally, it fails with *401.0 Unauthorized. "You do not have permission to view this directory or page"*.

I have read pages and pages and tried many options to no avail, such as:

- configured the following users to have full control of my code project folder (Everyone, IUSR, NETWORK SERVICE, ASP.NET, me, IIS_IUSRS, DefaultAppPool)
- checked that I have `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` in web.config
- configured an Application Pool using .NET v4 / Integrated.
- configured a new Site in IIS Manager using port 81 and my custom Application Pool
- tried Pass-through authentication or nominating myself as a specific user.

The error occurs in IE, Chrome and FF.

**Detailed Error Message**

```
HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Module  ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler
Error Code  0x00000000
Requested URL   http://localhost:81/
Physical Path   F:\Serko\Code\Analytics\SERKO.Analytics.Web
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

**Environment**

Windows 7 Ultimate, VS2012, IIS7.5

I do not have much hair left to pull out. Any idea why this does not run in IIS?

Comment: My own experience with 401 errors in IIS have always revolved around not granting permissions to the AppPoolIdentity. Have you granted permissions to "DefaultAppPool"?

Comment: Yes. That one also has permissions to the folder. (I've added it to my list above.)